# android studio jar import problems

Tags: java, android, jar

I am a freshman in android development and want to use webservice by some jars.(The webservice has been written and publish).
Then I use Ksoap.jar and Jsoup.jar.
In android studio. I try to import them. It shows successful but I still cannot use the classes in the jars.

The build.gradle shows below:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3-sources.jar')
}
```

But in my activity, I still cannot import them.
How can I solve this problem?
It drives me mad.

Comment: is this the master Build.Gradle file or the App one?

Comment: Did you execute "Sync gradles"? It will be exists in [Tools]-[Android]-[Sync Project with Gradle Files].

Comment: Also, check library dependencies of project at [File]-[Project Structure]-[Modules_app]-[Dependencies]. If your jar files are not exists at [Dependencies], you can't refer your custom libraries.

Comment: It is display in the Dependencies. But I still cannot use the class in the jar. For example, I type SoapObject(a class in KSOAP) and use alt+enter. Nothing adding on the top. How to do next step?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need

```
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-3.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.3-sources.jar')
```

As long as you have those jar files in the libs folder, this gradle line will include them in your project.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

It says "for every jar file in the `libs/` directory, compile it." Having those two additional lines is redundant.